# Why I cannot sleep in inn (such as sleeping giant inn)

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I went to sleeping giant inn. I saw a girl. I paid 10 coins. I tried again and the girl says are you kidding you already rent a room.

I don't know which room she is talking about. In a room she's in there is a bed. I can't sleep there. The bed is owned. Is that my room? I paid her 10 coins for it?

Comment: Check the other rooms. One of them will have a bed you can sleep in.

Comment: Should have paid attention to the dialogue. She would have told you which room was yours. Find the bed that isn't "owned".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you want to hire a bed in an Inn, when you first enter, all the beds will be "Owned", and therefore unavailable to sleep in. When you pay for a bed, one of them will become available (i.e. you will be able to sleep in it). More often than not you will be asked to follow the inn keeper as they show you to your room or some where near by it. If they get stuck they can finish their sequence with out giving you the information you need (took me forever to find my bad in the Inn in Windhelm due to this).

For the Sleeping Giant Inn, if you are standing with the bar on your right, the left door is the one you have rented out of the two to choose from (not including the one that leads back outside).

[image]